# Android error - No SIM card/Emergency calls only

Tags: bugs, gsm

The problem: phone doesn't want to register in network.

1. Android device shows **No SIM card**.
2. After playing with menu `*#*#4636#*#*` it starts showing **Emergency calls only**.
3. Phone displays available networks, but don't want register in it - says **Your SIM card doesn't allow a connection to this network** (*this means gsm module works well, but complains on sim card*).
4. This SIM card works well in another phone (*this means there is no issue with SIM*).
5. Any other SIM doesn't work in this phone (*in both slots: micro and nano*).
6. On inserting SIM-card phone asks sim's pin code and accepts it. (*this means that phone is communicating with sim well*)
7. In radio logs the following (*collected lines from long output, don't know how relevant is this*):

```
> E/SubscriptionController( 7326): getSubState: invalid subId = 2147483644 D/SubscriptionManager( 6723): [getPhoneId]- fail
> D/RilRequest( 7326): [4032] SET_NETWORK_SELECTION_MANUAL error: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: ILLEGAL_SIM_OR_ME ret= 
> D/RilRequest( 7326): [4173] E/GSM     ( 7326): Unrecognized RIL errno 7
> D/TelephonyManager(  495): No /proc/cmdline  exception=java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/cmdline: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) 
> E/TelephonyManager( 1078): hasMatchedTetherApnSetting NPE 
> E/TelephonyManager( 1078): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony.getTetherApnRequired()' on a null object reference
```

Full radio log (after ejecting/inserting SIM) http://paste.evervolv.com/view/d00213a4

8. More details I've posted on http://en.miui.com/thread-264222-1-1.html
   (in two words: *phone Xiaomi Mi Note Pro, never locked, worked before 6 month*).

I think this is wide spreaded Android bug - exists many complains on this issue.

Any suggestions?

**UPD1**: The SIM is factory micro-sim, not hand cutted one.

**UPD2**: I am not sure that logs are represents root cause of the bug.

**UPD3**: The root cause of failure was found in logs:

```
E/RILQ    (  964): (1/964): RIL[1][main] qcril_qmi_init_core_client_handles: qcril_qmi_presence_init returned failure(-3)
E/RILQ    (  964): (1/964): RIL[1][main] qcril_qmi_client_send_msg_sync: Failed to send sync qmi msg 0x03 w/(-2) QMI_SERVICE_ERR
```

This is error of QMI protocol communicating with GSM module. So this is chipset (Snapdragon 810 in this case) hardware error...

It was very loud to say 'android bug'... Android mistake was in hiding so much kind of errors behind common message 'No SIM card'.

**Closed.**

Comment: What kind of phone is it? Is it locked to a particular carrier?

Comment: Xiaomi Mi Note Pro, not locked. I guess this is common android issue. See i.e. http://thewichitacomputerguy.com/blog/how-i-fixed-your-sim-card-does-not-allow-connection-network-g1

Comment: That guy thinks the problem he was seeing was caused by the network, and it was seven years ago, so I don't think it's actually the same problem. Your problem looks specific to Xiaomi phones.

Comment: 1 - http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138613/lenovo-a3300-gv-tab-andorid-4-4-2-no-sim-card-emergency-call-only, 2 - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2698621, 3 - https://www.wiknix.com/how-to-fix-insert-sim-card-and-not-registered-on-network-error/, and more ...

Comment: None of those posts mention the logs you're seeing, and the two with "fixes" are both fixed by a reboot. If yours wasn't fixed by a reboot, it's not the same problem.

Comment: FWIW, I used to see the same error message a lot, but in my case it was because the SIM card was slightly too small and came away from the contacts. Not everyone with the same error message as you has the same problem.

Comment: I'm note sure this logs is related to this bug... It's just errors found in logs during registration.. May be root cause of this bug fails silenlty..

Comment: SIM card is not cutted, this is factory micro-sim. I've inserted this sim only one time, six moth ago.

Comment: On ''Your problem looks specific to Xiaomi phones' - I don't think that Xiaomi modifed root android code (SubscriptionController, TelephonyManager). It's very stable code and changed rarely.